# Kotlin. Is it possible to set log4j logger on the file level?

Tags: kotlin, log4j

I'm using log4j in my Kotlin application and set it as usual

`private val logger = LogManager.getLogger(this::class.java)`

I was wondering, is it possible to set logger outside of the class, on the file level? I guess I might pass it as a parameter for functions in this file which need logger, but maybe there is any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you will need to reference the class you want the logger to belong to (instead of `this`), or a simple String with the path if you desire.

You will have something like this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager

private val logger = LogManager.getLogger(Abc::class.java)

class Abc {
    fun etc(){
        logger.info("Hello")
    }
}

fun outsideOfTheClass(){
    logger.info("There")
}

object Xyz {
    fun insideSomethingElse(){
        logger.info("Hello there")
    }
}
```

If you do want a logger without reference to any class you can do:

```
val logger = LogManager.getLogger("TheNameOfTheLogger")
```

Comment: Hi @Alex, thank you for you answer. Now I understand that I have formulated my question wrong :) Originally I was wondering if it (making a logger inside of a file) is possible out of any class meaning no presence of any class in this file. But I guess in some cases I can follow your approach and create an artificial class for storing the logger inside of the file.

Comment: aa, sure you can. Just do `private val logger = LogManager.getLogger("TheNameOfTheLogger")` instead of a class name.

Comment: np, I've added this to the answer as well.